# filter query mongoldb Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to get a list of data that match specific queries but I am getting this error

> "(AtlasError) merchant is not allowed or the syntax is incorrect, see
> the Atlas documentation for more information"

```
func ...

var result []*model.Package

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    tokenData, err := middleware.CtxValue(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    orQuery := []bson.M{}
    merchant := "abc"
    completedQuery := bson.M{"status": "completed"}
    cancelledQuery := bson.M{"status": "cancelled"}
    orQuery = append(
        orQuery,
        cancelledQuery,
        completedQuery)
    limit64 := int64(limit)
    page64 := int64(page)
    match := bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"$nor": orQuery}}
    var filterQuery primitive.M

    if tokenData.Role == "admin" && merchant != nil {
        filterQuery = bson.M{"merchant": bson.M{"id": merchant}}
    } else {
        filterQuery = bson.M{"user": bson.M{"id": tokenData.Id}}
    }
    paginatedData, err1 := paginate.New(r.Collection).Context(ctx).Limit(limit64).Page(page64).Aggregate(match, filterQuery)
    if err1 != nil {
        return nil, err1
    }


...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filterQuery`, which seems to contain `{ "merchant" : { "id" : "abc" } }`, is being passed sepearately to `.Aggregate()`. But the aggregation framework is expecting to receive something that represents a sequence of pipeline stages. Each of these stages, outlined [here in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/), are expected to begin with a `$` character such as the `$match` stage.

Currently the database is attempting to process `merchant` as an `options` for the pipeline (see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and [here](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.11.0/mongo#Collection.Aggregate)). But such an option doesn't exist, hence the error message.

To resolve this, you should incorporate the `filterQuery` logic into the existing `match` variable/stage that you are building and passing. Alternatively you can wrap `filterQuery` in a different `$match` and then pass both of them (as a single argument) to `.Aggregate()`.

[This example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/aggregation/#omit-fields-in-results) in the documentation shows they build multiple [stages](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) and then submit them together to `.Aggregate()` via `mongo.Pipeline{...}`:

```
// create the stages
matchStage := bson.D{{"$match", bson.D{{"toppings", "milk foam"}}}}
unsetStage := bson.D{{"$unset", bson.A{"_id", "category"}}}
sortStage := bson.D{{"$sort", bson.D{
    {"price", 1},
    {"toppings", 1}},
}}
limitStage := bson.D{{"$limit", 2}}

// pass the stage into a pipeline
// pass the pipeline as the second paramter in the Aggregate() method
cursor, err := coll.Aggregate(context.TODO(), mongo.Pipeline{matchStage, unsetStage, sortStage, limitStage})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried your approach but it does not provide a solution for me. Would appreciate a definitive answer please.

Comment: Can you give some more details about what you did and what result/behaviors you observed? We can't refine the guidance without knowing more about how the proposed changes failed to provide the solution.

Comment: I cannot use $match twice. in the original code I shared, I am trying to get data from database based on an id and an $nor operation for the type of data to be retrieved for that particular user.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I'm not sure why you can't use $match twice? That's certainly valid from MongoDB's perspective and [the database will even combine them together for you](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#-match----match-coalescence). Even if you choose not to take that approach, I also suggested the alternative of combining that additional filter to your existing `match` variable. Both approaches should work fine.

Comment: Thanks. works now.